# "TypeError: this.setState(...) is undefined" when making a promise after setting state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a full stack application using the MERN stack to encrypt text through classic algorithms. On the frontend it has a form to input text, the desired algorithm and the factor(s) to use. It's supposed to render the encrypted text as it's being typed, so I have a function to handle any changes to the form - right now it's a work in progress, hence the console.logs:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import CipherService from './../../services/ciphers.service'

import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form'

import './InputForm.css'

class InputForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      text: '',
      cipher: 'caesar',
      factor: 13,
    }

    this.cipherService = new CipherService()
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    let { value, name } = e.target
    if (name === 'factor') {
      value = parseInt(value)
    }
    this.setState({ [name]: value })
      .then(() => {
        switch (this.state.cipher) {
          case 'caesar':
            this.cipherService
              .caesar(this.state)
              .then((result) => console.log(result.data.message))
              .catch((err) => console.log(err))
            break
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Form.Group as='section'>
        <Form.Control as='textarea' name='text' onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <Form.Text className='text-muted'>
          Please only input Latin characters without diacritics or spaces.
        </Form.Text>
        <div className='options-container'>
          <Form.Control as='select' name='cipher' onChange={this.handleChange}>
            <option value='caesar'>Caesar cipher</option>
          </Form.Control>
          <Form.Control
            as='input'
            type='number'
            name='factor'
            value={13}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        </div>
      </Form.Group>
    )
  }
}

export default InputForm
```

As it is right now, if the state of the form changes, the app crashes outputting this error:

```js
TypeError: this.setState(...) is undefined
InputForm/this.handleChange
src/components/InputForm/InputForm.js:25
  22 | if (name === 'factor') {
  23 |   value = parseInt(value)
  24 | }
> 25 | this.setState({ [name]: value })
     | ^  26 |   .then(() => {
  27 |     switch (this.state.cipher) {
  28 |       case 'caesar':
```

I'm guessing it's a context problem, but I can't find the exact thing that is causing it. Making it so the function calls the API after it parses the this.setState, no promises, makes it work, but because setState is an asynchronous action, it passes the "previous" state to the API, with undesired results.

Comment: Could you please post the entire InputForm.js or at least all usages of `handleChange`?

Comment: have you tried using a *function* instead of an *arrow function*? I don't know the whole code but with arrow function you don't have the ```this``` of the hosting object when the function is called, instead you have the ```this``` of the scope where the arrow function was declared

Comment: @BenjaminEckardt sure! Just edited the question to include the whole InputForm.js

Comment: @asdru Tried to do so, exactly the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setState` is asynchronous but it doesn't return a promise for you to use `.then` on it. It however provides a callback as the second argument, that you can use

```
this.setState({ [name]: value }, () => {
     switch (this.state.cipher) {
           case 'caesar':
            this.cipherService
              .caesar(this.state)
              .then((result) => console.log(result.data.message))
              .catch((err) => console.log(err))
            break
        }

});
```

Comment: @JaredSmith No you are mistaken. handleChange is implemented as an arrow function